# Getting the first URL of an image search result with google image API in PHP

Tags: php, image

did you know a php script (a class will be nice) who get the url of the first image result of a google api image search? Thanks

Example.

```
<?php echo(geturl("searchterm")) ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able do that easily with **[Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**.

**Note:** See the examples on their site for more information.

- A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!
- Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.

Comment: there is a google API, with standard outputs, parsing an html its NOT a good practice

Comment: @DomingoSL: I would never use a bunch of APIs for such trivial task.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution to get the first image from Google Image result using Simple HTML DOM as Sarfraz told.

Kindly check the below code. Currently it is working fine for me.

```
$search_keyword=str_replace(' ','+',$search_keyword);
$newhtml =file_get_html("https://www.google.com/search?q=".$search_keyword."&tbm=isch");
$result_image_source = $newhtml->find('img', 0)->src;
echo '<img src="'.$result_image_source.'">';
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, it works very well. I'm just wondering, are you able to extract the original url, not the encrypted picture, in the same way?

Comment: Can you explain what is encrypted picture?

Comment: Yes, I called them "encrypted" cause actually what your code gets is the small-size version of the picture, let's say the thumbnails. If you look at the resulting url they are named by google "encrypted". Do you know instead how to get the original size version? The problem is that if you resize the encrypted ones, they have really bad quality, so you can't get more than a very tiny picture..