# Pull random image from a google image search with jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery, google-image-search

Is there a way to display a random image from a google image search?

preferably using jquery or php?

Comment: There is already a similar question with an excellent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018428/getting-the-first-url-of-an-image-search-result-with-google-image-api-in-php

Comment: Funny I just posted this in other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436799/random-image-url-from-google#33827461